# Salvando a atividade do usuario no banco de dados(sql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou criando um gráfico para analisar o acesso de posts pela faixa etária por horário no meu site. Porém o site ainda não possui essa capacidade de capturar a atividade do usuario e preciso faze-la.

Minha tarefa e alterar o banco de dados para que isso seja possível, atualmente tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
table user{
    id_user (Chave Primaria);
    date_of_birth (date);
    name (char(255))
}

table post{
    id_post (Chave Primaria);
    title (char(255))
}
```

Quando um usuario 'Tobias' acessar o posts 'Como assar um ovo' no dia '23 de  maio de 2018' às '13:31' durante '30 segundos', precisarei ter essa informação no banco de dados.

Primeiramente pensei em criar uma tabela da forma mais intuitiva possível:

```
table acesso{
    id_acesso(Chave primaria);
    id_user (Chave estrangeira);
    id_post(Chave estrangeira);
    date (timestamp);
    duration (inteiro, segundos);
}
```

Porém não sei qual é a maneira mais eficiente de fazer essa tabela ou se existe uma formar melhor ou se estou fazendo o certo. Pois estou planejando essa banco para ter milhares de usuarios e posts, e eficiencia é algo desejado.

Comment: Antes de mais nada, as ferramentas do Google não te ajudariam nessa demanda? No caso, o analytics?

Comment: Eu pensei nessa possibilidade, mas atualmente terei que fazer meu proprio analytics, estou fazendo um gráfico em d3 e vou usar as informações que eu irei adquirir para criar meus proprios gráficos.

Comment: Dessa forma, só vai gravar os dados dos usuários que tem alguma tipo de cadastro em seu sistema.

Comment: Bom nesse caso, tenha em mente que quanto mais informações melhor! Saiba também, que nem sempre terá as informações que precisa. Pergunto:  Será que a posição geográfica do usuário não seria interessante para você? Se sim, seria legal colocar latitude e longitude nessa base. Recomendaria também uma estrutura não relacional. Talvez um mongodb. Motivo: Você terá muitas informações nessa base. Com esse tipo de banco de dados você terá mais performance em suas consultas e uma organização dos dados mais coerente.

Comment: Você também pode utilizar o tipo `jsonb` do postgres para armazenar essas informações. Se não me engano a partir da 9.4 ele já tem suporte a índices inclusive. Também lembro de ter visto um artigo divulgando que a performance do postgres com o jsonb foi melhor que a do mongodb, mas não consegui localizar o link.